# React-native android error when running the npx react-native run-android command

Tags: android, react-native

**Android**

This is the error got when I am trying to run my react-native project

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
BUILD FAILED in 1m 58s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Make sure you have the Android development environment set up
```

I think you need local.properties file in your project with sdk path in it.

[image]